# Create jsTree from D3 Tree Layout with toggled nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, jstree

I am trying to learn more about D3 and jquery, so please excuse any mistakes.

I have successfully "remixed" the d3 tree layout to give me a zoomable tree layout, but now I would like to build a jstree where the user can toggle on/off certain nodes to show the lowest grain of a detail in the tree (currently the click function prevents the tree from going down to this grain).

I was able to redirect the click event on the 2nd to lowest level to a different function like this:

```
function click(d) {
            if (d.depth != 4) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
                update(d);
            }
            else
            {
                var circle = d3.select(this).selectAll("circle");
                var togglestate;
                console.log(circle.style("fill"));
                if  (circle.style("fill") == "#b0c4de") {
                    togglestate="on";
                    circle.style("fill","red");
                    toggleNode(togglestate,d);
                }
                else {
                    togglestate="off";
                    circle.style("fill","lightsteelblue");
                    toggleNode(togglestate,d);
                }
            } 
        }
```

Then in the I think in the toggleNode function, I need to "build" a JSON object that I can pass to jsTree to build the tree, but I am afraid this is pushing the limits of my understanding.  Can someone help educate me?

I prepared a fully working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bGa48/).

I'm not sure how to get jstree on the same jsfiddle, but I can say that the JSON format from the jstree website is something like this:

```
$('#using_json').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       'Simple root node',
       {
         'text' : 'Root node 2',
         'state' : {
           'opened' : true,
           'selected' : true
         },
         'children' : [
           { 'text' : 'Child 1' },
           'Child 2'
         ]
      }
    ]
} });
```

Somehow I need to glue these two parts together. Again, I am sure that there are better ways to achieve the result, but I have not discovered them yet.

Comment: Not sure about others but I am having difficulties parsing your question. Notwithstanding the fact that in my opinion you chose a tough path to learn d3 and jquery, by mishmashing quite different implementations of tree structures, please look at this [example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) and tell me if the click function here prevents one from going to the "lowest grain of a detail" which I am presuming to be the leaf node information...

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes I agree, this is a complicated question!  That example isn't exactly the same idea.  I stop at a certain depth in the tree layout (in this example, it's 4).  It is that level that I want to put into a jstree object.  I am actually getting a bit closer I think by parsing the data object to put it into the correct format for jstree to build a tree.

Comment: Updated my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGa48/3/) with my latest attempt at the toggleNode function.  It writes the JSON object to the console, but if you compare this with the jstree prescribed format, it is not exactly the same.  I am trying to figure out how to align it to the jstree format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it on my own.  Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGa48/4/) with the final solution.  There must be a more elegant way to get this done.

I just wrote this toggleNode function to handle parsing the d3 object into the JSON format for the jsTree

```
    function toggleNode(togglestate,data)
    {
       var cleanchild = new Array();
        data._children.forEach( function (d) { cleanchild.push( {text: d.name + "-" + d.DET_TYPE + "-" + d.DET_DATE} ) });
        jtree =  { core: { data: [ {text: data.name,children:  cleanchild   } ] } };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jtree));
        //$('#jstree').jstree(jtree);

    }
```

Comment: Now that you got the JSON right, how do you intend to render the jstree inside the d3 tree? I am assuming you want to do this eventually unless this is the full extent of your exercise (which is fine, not being critical). Since jstree is implemented with html elements, the only way you will be able to place them inside svg, as far as I know, is via the svg:foreignObject element, which is [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject), in case that matters.

Comment: ah, I think I see where my question was confusing.  The jsTree is in a separate div located elsewhere on the page. I just sort of hijack the click event on the svg element to determine what to populate in the jsTree...clear as mud I assume.  I would have made the jsfiddle a bit more robust, but I had some trouble getting jsTree to play nice with jsFiddle.  I totally agree with you on the difficulty of mixing svg and html.